# Удалить из переменный часть текста

Tags: javascript, jquery, переменные

Есть переменная fileWay - это пути к загруженным файлам на сервере разделенные символом ";" тегом перевода строки пример:

```
/home/j/23412353rt2/sait.ru/public_html/uploads/файл.pdf;<br>/home/j/23412353rt2/sait.ru/public_html/uploads/файл.pdf;<br>/home/j/23412353rt2/sait.ru/public_html/uploads/файл.pdf;<br>/home/j/23412353rt2/sait.ru/public_html/uploads/файл.pdf;<br>
```

/home/j/23412353rt2/sait.ru/public_html/uploads/ - этот путь у всех файлов одинаковый, но количество и название файлов может меняться.

В итоте нужно получить что-то вроде

```
https://sait.ru/uploads/файл.pdf;<br>https://sait.ru/uploads/файл.pdf;<br>https://sait.ru/uploads/файл.pdf;<br>https://sait.ru/uploads/файл.pdf;<br>https://sait.ru/uploads/файл.pdf;<br>https://sait.ru/uploads/файл.pdf;<br>https://sait.ru/uploads/файл.pdf;<br>
```

пробовал код ниже но он только для одного файла. как его адаптировать для моего случия?

```
var srcfileWay = fileWay;
var element = srcfileWay.split('/');
newfileWay = 'https://sait.ru/uploads/' + element[element.length - 1]
```

Да, это повтор вопроса, не судите строго, но с первого раза я не разобрался, а при редактировании уже ни кто не отвечал на мой вопрос. (надеюсь на понимание)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все вхождения фиксированной строки можно заменить другой фиксированной строкой с помощью метода `replace` и регулярного выражения:

```js
var fileWay = "/home/j/23412353rt2/sait.ru/public_html/uploads/файл.pdf;<br>/home/j/23412353rt2/sait.ru/public_html/uploads/файл.pdf;<br>/home/j/23412353rt2/sait.ru/public_html/uploads/файл.pdf;<br>/home/j/23412353rt2/sait.ru/public_html/uploads/файл.pdf;<br>";
var result = fileWay.replace(/\/home\/j\/23412353rt2\/sait\.ru\/public_html/g, "https://sait.ru");
console.log(result);
```